# What is the formula to get all holidays, including Saturday, Sunday, and public holidays?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to write a simple automated spreadsheet that counts how many hours every employee have worked. I managed to add 8 hours if it is a weekday, and recognize if it is Saturday or Sunday.

I can't figure out how to add public holidays to my calendar. Public holiday list should be on another sheet.

The formula I use:
=IF(WEEKDAY(E$7;2)<6; 8; "B")

Here is the actual spreadsheet: https://wetransfer.com/downloads/9108e8df968b00f0bde2b6a169f9488220190605171849/47588a

For example, I need to show that 25th of December is a holiday, despite it falling on a workday.

Comment: You can import the list of days that are holidays in the proper region from some other place and look up if the worked days fall into that list. You can just google those days.

Comment: List of public holidays aint no problem. I just don't know how to combine it all in one formula

Answer (score 1):

I created a small list of holidays in range D3-D5, and used following formula, showing either a number (holiday) or showing "No Holiday":

```
=IFNA(MATCH(B2;D$3:D$5;0);"No Holiday")
```

Comment: how could I marge your formula with mine =IF(WEEKDAY(E$7;2)<6; 8; "B") ?
E$7 is the day of current month.

Comment: Using the `AND()` worksheet function: `=AND(IFNA(...);IF(WEEKDAY(...)))`.